# MS Access Data Macro- After Insert in the same table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table

```
TransactionID
MemberID
Code
TransactionDate
BatchNo
TransactionType
Amount
Description
```

The scenario is everytime i insert a new record it will create a ValidationNo Using the Columns in my table(Code, TransactionDate and BatchNo)

Using Before Update is working, but what i want is it will create only After Insert.

[Below is my macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgiYI.jpg)

Comment: That sounds like a terrible plan. If you insert a new record when creating a record in the same table, that will trigger the macro to insert a new record into the same table, which will trigger the macro again, and again, until your database is 2GB of size and no more new records can be added. Also, it likely defeats normalization.

Answer (score 0):

I got it i used

**IsInsert** and **Setfield** in **Before Change**

Here is my Macro
[Before Change Data Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LroYg.png)

Thank you